# How to upload equal documents from different users to the server in php?

Tags: php

User A enters the web application and uploads the "info.pdf" document. In parallel, a user B who entered the web system on another computer, uploads the document "info.pdf" at the same time as user A. Since both have the same name, I ask what would be the best strategy to implement so that these files remain in a directory on the server, associated in the database to the users who uploaded it and then later, each user can recover Your documents uploaded.

What would be the most efficient way to implement this theme? What should be added to each file name so that these names were unique and had no problems copying to the destination directory on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use timestamp, underscore,user-id before the file name like

```
$filename=time()."_".$UserId.$yourFileName
```

You can put the user id from session and filename from $_FILES

Then every file have the unique name.

Answer (score 1):

The strategy would be simple in that case. you can override the filename before uploaded it on storage and store real name and generated name in database with user primary key in table. after that you can simple give them a link with original filename in HTML5 download attribute.

Have a look pseudo code.

```
<?php
$original_filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filename = time() . '_' . $filename;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $filename))
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO media(user_id, file_name, original_name) VALUES ( $userId, $filename, $original_filename);
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
} ?>
```

and now you can display link via html5 download attribute to download with original filename.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM medias where user_id = $userId LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
<a href="<?= $row['filename'] ?>" download="<?= $row['original_filename']; ?>"><?= $row['original_filename']; ?></a>
```